# Program flow in PHP/jQuery application - Can it be simplified?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm working on some code I've inherited and I'm not quite experienced enough to know if the way it currently works is as over-complex as it seems to be. I know that the project has had several developers working on it, including some inexperienced ones.

There is a script included in the header containing an IIFE which returns a function called `bind_events`, which takes an argument called `settings`

```
// scroll-events.js
var scroll_events = (function ($) {
    return {
    bind_events: function (settings) {
        scroll_elements = settings.scroll_elements;
        click_elements = settings.click_elements;
    }
    };
})();
```

In footer.php, there is an `echo` statement containing a jQuery document ready function which calls the function returned by the IIFE defined in scroll-events.js, interpolating PHP variables as parameter values.

```
echo "
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
scroll_events.bind_events({
    \"universal\":".$universal.",
    \"page\":\"".$page
    })
});
"
```

I'm working in WordPress, and have the ability to easily localize PHP variables so JS scripts have access to them.

I'd like to know if the current way of doing things is as convoluted as it seems, and how the same result could be achieved in a more easy-to-follow-and-debug way?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right fit for SO as you don't have a specific problem, maybe try on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: and if this code is used in WordPress, you may have more help for that on the site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com